# How to Ensure Security and Reliability in OTA Installations?

Tags: ios, ota

I'm currently working on setting up an OTA (Over-The-Air) installation process for our mobile applications and want to ensure that the method I use is in line with industry best practices for security and reliability.

I'm not looking for opinions, but rather concrete practices that are widely recognized and adopted by professionals in the field of mobile development and deployment.

Specifically, I'd like to know:

1. How to properly secure the distribution of OTA updates to protect against unauthorized access and tampering.
2. Methods to ensure the integrity of the application files being transmitted.
3. Techniques for ensuring compatibility with different device types and OS versions during the OTA update process.
4. Strategies for rolling out updates to staggered user groups to minimize risk.
5. Ways to handle update failures and ensure that devices can recover gracefully without user intervention.

I've searched for resources and found various bits of information, but I'm looking for a consolidated list of best practices that are considered the gold standard for OTA installations.

Note: My environment involves deploying mobile applications on both Android and iOS platforms.

Could anyone with experience in this area provide some guidance or point me toward any authoritative resources on this topic?

Comment: The app store handles all of that for iOS.